# Extract details from log file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, logging

Log file consists lines of format like below:

I, [2018-03-07T10:21:26.315799 #7531]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command *git-upload-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/GitLab-write-logs/write-logs.git> for user with key key-1.

From the above file, I need extarct few logging details, This log file captures all the  git ssh activities and after certain time, it stores the  captured details in different tar file and this file refreshes and again starts storing log details from blank page..This action repeats.

**Example:** If the line consists of "git-upload-" then it should the execute the loop . But I want my script to execute every minute using cron job because the log file updates frequently and how should I avoid the repeat of extracting same details, like If I have already extracted details from a line at particular time stamp then I shouldn't extract the same details. How can I write the loop here using shell script.

Comment: @Prs see how you can use `cat <filename>|egrep "git-upload|somethingElseYouWantToGrepGoesHere|AnotherPattern" | tee targetPatternMatchedFile.txt; tail -f <filename> | egrep "git-upload|somethingElseYouWantToGrepGoesHere|AnotherPattern" | tee -a targetPatternMatchedFile.txt`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*